# Getting a ConcurrentModificationException on Arraylist.iterator().next(), but I haven't changed the original list

Tags: java, iterator

I have the following code which is part of a longer section of code that's intended to turn an object graph into a flat tree such that this tree can then be processed further by existing code:

```
private void addProjectStreamsFromGraphToTree(String parentIndex, Map<String, Object> objectTree, ProjectTreeView projectTreeView) {
        Set<Integer> allConnectedLevelOids = new HashSet<Integer>();
        // Set in the tree + add everything underneath projectStream:
        int index = 1;
        String treeIndex ="";
        for (Iterator<ExportableProjectStreamView> iter = projectTreeView.getProjectStreamList().iterator(); iter.hasNext(); index++) {
            // Getting the concurrentModificationException on the below line
            ProjectStreamView projectStreamView = (ProjectStreamView) iter.next();
            treeIndex = parentIndex + "." + index;
            objectTree.put(treeIndex, projectStreamView);
            addLifeCyclesFromGraphToTree(allConnectedLevelOids, projectStreamView , treeIndex, objectTree, projectTreeView);
        }

    }

private void addLifeCyclesFromGraphToTree(Set<Integer> allConnectedLevelOids, ProjectStreamView projectStreamView, String parentIndex, Map<String, Object> objectTree, ProjectTreeView projectTreeView) {

    int index = 1;
    String treeIndex ="";

    ExportableLifecycleView lifecycleView = projectTreeView.getLifecycleList().stream().filter(lcv -> projectStreamView.getLifecycleOid().equals(lcv.getOid())).findFirst().get();

    treeIndex = parentIndex + "." + index;
    objectTree.put(treeIndex, lifecycleView);

    // add the levels that are linked to this lifecycle and at once add all oids of the levels,
    // connected to this lifecycle, to the allconnectedLevelOids.       
    allConnectedLevelOids.addAll(addConnectedLevelsFromGraphToTree(lifecycleView, treeIndex, objectTree, projectTreeView));
}

protected Set<Integer> addConnectedLevelsFromGraphToTree(ExportableLifecycleView lifecycleView, String parentIndex, Map<String, Object> objectTree, ProjectTreeView projectTreeView) {

    Set<Integer> connectedLevelOids = new HashSet<Integer>();

    int index = 1;
    String treeIndex ="";
    for (Iterator<ExportableLifecycleAssociationView> iter = lifecycleView.getLifecycleAssociations().iterator(); iter.hasNext(); index++) {
        ExportableLifecycleAssociationView exportableLifecycleAssociationView = iter.next();
        treeIndex = parentIndex + "." + index;
        objectTree.put(treeIndex, exportableLifecycleAssociationView);
        ExportableLevelView connectedLevelView = projectTreeView.getLevelList().stream().filter(level -> level.getOid().equals(exportableLifecycleAssociationView.getLevelOid())).findFirst().get();
        index++;
        treeIndex = parentIndex + "." + index;
        objectTree.put(treeIndex, connectedLevelView);

        // add the levels to the returning hashset:
        connectedLevelOids.add(connectedLevelView.getOid());
    }      
    return connectedLevelOids;
}
```

As you can see, I never interact with projectTreeView.getProjectStreamList() except to get the iterator, and I never call a .remove() or a .add() on any list. The only things I do that change things are put() on the tree map and .add on a local HashSet(). I also don't change the original projectTreeView in any way, and I only read properties on the projectStreamView I retrieve using the iterator.

Still, I am getting the following error:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
        at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:909) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:859) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at be.ikan.scm4all.business.server.bs.clone.ProjectImportExportServiceImpl.addProjectStreamsFromGraphToTree(ProjectImportExportServiceImpl.java:615) ~[classes/:?]
        at be.ikan.scm4all.business.server.bs.clone.ProjectImportExportServiceImpl.getProjectTreeFromGraph(ProjectImportExportServiceImpl.java:604) ~[classes/:?]
        at be.ikan.scm4all.business.server.bs.clone.ProjectImportExportServiceImpl.importProject(ProjectImportExportServiceImpl.java:515) ~[classes/:?]
        at be.ikan.scm4all.client.rest.controller.projectimportexport.ProjectImportRestController.importProject(ProjectImportRestController.java:110) ~[classes/:?]
```

Is there some other rule of iterators that I'm breaking here? Why am I getting this exception even though I'm not changing the original list? This seems like it might have something to do with the iterator in addConnectedLevelsFromGraphToTree(), but that one iterates over an entirely different list in a different part of the tree. Do ArrayLists share iterator state or something?

Comment: It's hard to give a definite answer here. It's not clear what `projectTreeView.getProjectStreamList()` does. You're calling some other methods on this view, and these methods *might* modify the list that is returned by `getProjectStreamList`. A hacky workaround *could* be to create a defensive copy: `List<X> list = new ArrayList<X>(....getProjectStreamList());`, and then only iterate over *this* list. But this might only "hide" the issue, and the results may be inconsistent as long as the behavior of `projectTreeView` is not clearly specified...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some checking, and I found out what caused it. Turns out that there is a bug in `projectTreeView.getLevelList()`. I sort my list before returning it using `Collections.sort()`, and instead of sorting `levelList` there, I sort `projectStreamList`...